# Unable to get Google OAuth Token

Tags: php, oauth, google-api-php-client

I'm trying to add calendar events to my Google calendar from a php script. Note that I can do this successfully directly from a Google test [page](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert) so I think that my calendar is set up correctly. However, when I attempt do this from a php script, I'm not able to get the OAuth2 token.

The following script, mostly taken from a Google example, runs without error, but it always winds up with a "Connect Me!" link. When I click on this link, it takes me to a validation screen that warns me that this app would like to manage my calendars. I click 'Accept' and a then see my calendar. A little inconvenient, but if this gets the OAuth token, fine.

I then go back and run the script again, hoping that the access token will now be available, but I get exactly the same result. No matter how many times I run this script, I never get the token, which I need in order to expand the script to add events to the calendar.

I've been at this for days, and I'm just not getting anywhere. Can anyone help? Thanks.

```
<?php
require_once '../../src/Google_Client.php';
require_once '../../src/contrib/Google_CalendarService.php';
require_once '../../src/auth/Google_OAuth2.php';

session_start();

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("Add Google Calendar Entries");

// Visit https://code.google.com/apis/console?api=calendar to generate your
// client id, client secret, and to register your redirect uri.
$client->setClientId('843319906820-1s1d737e77o71a3vaskf434k3ape1fk5.apps.googleusercontent.com');
$client->setClientSecret('AP5imn3e0TEWNyLTCNm8YJj6');
$client->setRedirectUri('https://www.google.com/calendar/');
$client->setDeveloperKey('AIzaSyDIw3ks7AmrIrRxjO9y2gWBhQDYHFWd-uc');
$client->setUseObjects(true);

$cal = new Google_CalendarService($client);

if (isset($_GET['logout'])) {
  unset($_SESSION['token']);
}

if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
  $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
  $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
  header('Location: http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
}

if (isset($_SESSION['token'])) {
  $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);
}

if ($client->getAccessToken()) {
  $calList = $cal->calendarList->listCalendarList();
  print "<h1>Calendar List</h1><pre>" . print_r($calList, true) . "</pre>";

  $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();

} else {
  $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
  print "<a class='login' href='$authUrl'>Connect Me!</a>";
}

?>
```

EDIT: Attempting to implement the suggestion from Vinicius Pinto. I've changed my redirect to point directly back to this script. Now I get this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Google_ServiceException' with message
>   'Error calling GET
>   https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/users/me/calendarList?key=AIzaSyDIw3ks7AmrIrRxjO9y2gWBhQDYHFWd-uc:
>   (403) Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to
>   activate the API for your project.' in
>   D:\Hosting\11347607\html\scripts\google-api-php-client\src\io\Google_REST.php:66
>   Stack trace: #0
>   D:\Hosting\11347607\html\scripts\google-api-php-client\src\io\Google_REST.php(36):
>   Google_REST::decodeHttpResponse(Object(Google_HttpRequest)) #1
>   D:\Hosting\11347607\html\scripts\google-api-php-client\src\service\Google_ServiceResource.php(186):
>   Google_REST::execute(Object(Google_HttpRequest)) #2
>   D:\Hosting\11347607\html\scripts\google-api-php-client\src\contrib\Google_CalendarService.php(205):
>   Google_ServiceResource->__call('list', Array) #3
>   D:\Hosting\11347607\html\scripts\google-api-php-client\examples\calendar\simple.php(43):
>   Google_CalendarListServiceResource->listCalen in
>   D:\Hosting\11347607\html\scripts\google-api-php-client\src\io\Google_REST.php
>   on line 66

It would appear that I don't have the correct APIs activated in the developer console. I have the `Calendar API` and the `Google Cloud Storage JSON API` activated and nothing else. I don't see any other APIs that would be relevant, and I don't think that this message is telling me which APIs it wants.

EDIT 2: Looks like I was using the wrong developer key. I've changed it to the key for server applications. Now my error is this:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Google_AuthException' with message
>   'Error refreshing the OAuth2 token, message: '{ "error" :
>   "invalid_client" }'' in
>   D:\Hosting\11347607\html\scripts\google-api-php-client\src\auth\Google_OAuth2.php:288
>   Stack trace: #0
>   D:\Hosting\11347607\html\scripts\google-api-php-client\src\auth\Google_OAuth2.php(248):
>   Google_OAuth2->refreshTokenRequest(Array) #1
>   D:\Hosting\11347607\html\scripts\google-api-php-client\src\auth\Google_OAuth2.php(225):
>   Google_OAuth2->refreshToken('1/6ZdJyZALqcbwW...') #2
>   D:\Hosting\11347607\html\scripts\google-api-php-client\src\service\Google_ServiceResource.php(167):
>   Google_OAuth2->sign(Object(Google_HttpRequest)) #3
>   D:\Hosting\11347607\html\scripts\google-api-php-client\src\contrib\Google_CalendarService.php(205):
>   Google_ServiceResource->__call('list', Array) #4
>   D:\Hosting\11347607\html\scripts\google-api-php-client\examples\calendar\simple.php(47):
>   Google_CalendarListServiceResource->listCalendarList() in
>   D:\Hosting\11347607\html\scripts\google-api-php-client\src\auth\Google_OAuth2.php
>   on line 288

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$client->setRedirectUri()` should receive a URL pointing to your application, because this is the URL that you'll be redirected to after you authorize the application in the Google page. That's why you are being redirect to the calendar, because you are using the calendar URL.

It seems like your script is already expecting a $_GET['code'], so try setting the redirect URL to the url of this script. You'll also need to set the same URL in the Developers Console, under API -> Credentials.

You only get a token when you call `$client->authenticate($_GET['code']);` with a value code.

Take a look at [this lib I just commited to Github](https://github.com/viniciuspinto/gapiauth), it's an early version, but it's working fine (I'm using to access YouTube). It's using the [new official library](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client).

**Update:** as said in the comments, the developer key isn't actually required for this to work, even though all Google sample code sets it.

Comment: Thank you, @ViniciusPinto. I've changed that redirect, and am now getting a 403 error about APIs not being activated. If you have the patience for this (and the pity for me!) will you please look at the edit that I posted. Maybe this is as simple as turning on another API, but I don't know which one(s) it needs, other than the Calendar API, which is already activated. Thank you again. I really appreciate it!

Comment: I think it only requires the Calendar API on, the script is working fine for me. Double check your credentials and make sure you're using the credentials for the correct project. I'm not sure what else could be the problem.

Comment: I've checked them over and over. There are some choices that I need to make(like do I use the key for server applications or the one for browser applications) that I might be mistaking. I've temporarily included a screen shot of my entire developer console for this project. It's all just test data, and I'll regenerate these keys and remove the screenshot later. Would you please take a look at this and see if I am missing something? Thanks again. You are a life saver.

Comment: the developer key should be the API key under "Key for server applications"

Comment: Thank you, yet again. I made this change. I'm getting a slightly different error, which I take as progress. There are a few other posts on this error, but no answers. I think that I am almost there. Do you have any thoughts on how to fix this? I hate to keep bothering you, but I can't find any answers. Thank you.

Comment: hmm, I'm not sure, but have you tried clearing your cookies? it looks like it's trying to use the token that is in your session and that was created with the wrong credentials...

Comment: I got it. Finally. Your suggestion about clearing cookies got me past that error, but another one arose. I was able to find a solution to that one that finally resolved everything. Turns out that the final solution was to remove any references to the developer key. I'll mark your answer as the solution, but for the sake of others, would you mind updating the part about removing the developer key, assuming you agree with it? Thanks again for all of your help! Couldn't have resolved it without you.

Comment: great! I didn't know the developer key wasn't required, the docs says you should set it. I added a note to the answer.